# Scheme not starting with alphabetic character (at character 1) DART

Tags: dart

i just tried to get an image from network using this function

```
 Completer<ImageInfo> completer = Completer();
  Future<ui.Image> getImage(String path) async {
    [var img = new NetworkImage(path);
    img.resolve(ImageConfiguration()).addListener(ImageStreamListener((ImageInfo info,bool _){
      completer.complete(info);
    }));][1]
    ImageInfo imageInfo = await completer.future;
    return imageInfo.image;
  }
```

but i got a problem which i couldn't solve. Full error in attached [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Cpjr.png).

Comment: Did you found a solution? thanks!!

Answer (score 27):

Look around for any non-alphabetic character in URI. For me, it was a space char before 'https'.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me. I was using a localhost but forgot to add the `http://` before my IP address and port number. Adding that resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

well, it works now, just be sure to copy a link of an image and not an html page (right click and cpy the image Location)

Answer (score 0):

remove the (") from both the start and end

url.replaceAll('"', '');

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have added 'http://' before your IP address.